# Creating a bash command to automate telnet session and tee the output?

Tags: linux, bash

Can anyone please help me create a bash command to automate a telnet session?

1. telnet into session and tee the output.
2. input E.
3. input B.
4. input enter key in a loop until "End of file" is tee'd into file.
5. input x
6. input x
7. input escape command "^]"
8. input quit to quit the telnet session

Here is what i've come up with so far but its not working.

```
{ echo "E"; sleep 0.1; echo "B"; sleep 0.1; } | ( 
    telnet 10.10.10.4 | tee text.txt ) & 
    while sleep 0.1; do
        if grep -q "End of file" text.txt; then break; fi
    done && echo "x" && echo "x" && echo "^]" && echo "quit"
```

Here is the error:

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
Trying 10.10.10.4...
[1]  + broken pipe  { echo "E"; sleep 0.2; echo "B"; sleep 0.2; } | 
       done         ( telnet 10.10.10.4 | tee text.txt; )
```

Comment: Why running in background with `&` ?

Comment: Look at the `expect` utility. It will take a little time to get working, but if you need to do this sort of thing regularly, it will be worth the time spent to learn it. Good luck.

Comment: "*telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused*" this has nothing to do with your script or commands.  Fix this first.  You have something blocking your connection, most probably a firewall in between or on the server itself.  On another note, look into ssh.  Telnet is not encrypted and very poor form a security standpoint.  It should be turned off on any hardened server.

Comment: Sleep can only handle integers, btw, and 1 second is the smallest unit.

Comment: @tink, GNU `sleep` (the standard on Linux) can handle non-integer seconds.  `sleep 0.1` sleeps for (roughly) a 10th of a second on Linux.

Comment: Ooops ... brain-fart. Sorry - culling my comment ;) @pjh